# how should i Analyze complete db Schema And How does MongoDB Compass Schema Analyze work?

Tags: mongodb, schema, analyzer, mongodb-compass

How does MongoDB Compass Schema Analyze work?
I want to analyze the complete DB schema with all collections,
using MongoDB compass schema Analyze it will give data regarding about only one collection
I want to analyze the whole DB Schema

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.